# MySQL select query Using JSON_CONTAIN Alternative

Tags: mysql

There is a project table with a JSON column 'departments', it contains the department ids of the project, like '[dp1, dp2, dp3]'

Now I have a list of department ids AList, like AList = [dp3, dp4, dp5], and I need to find the project which department list contains one of the ids in AList.

Now I use json_contains to do this query, like 'select * from project_table where json_contains(JSON_ARRAY(AList), departments)'

However, the query is too slow, taking like 5 seconds to execute. Is there any other way to make the query quicker, or re-organize the table structure to fulfill the query scene?

Comment: JSON_OVERLAPS()

Comment: Consider using RDBMS structures (tables and columns and JOINs) instead of JSON.